# Why is there a difference between RAID order and Linux device order?

Tags: linux, mount, uefi, raid

I create 2 virtual disks. one is **RAID 0(HDD0)**. another is **RAID 1(HDD1, HDD2)**.

I chose physical devices in order.

But, After I install OS, **I found there is difference between RAID order and Disk order**.

I wanted disk status in order.

| NAME | RAID |
| --- | --- |
| sda | RAID0 |
| sdb | RAID1 |

I found disk status below.

| NAME | RAID |
| --- | --- |
| sda | RAID1 |
| sdb | RAID0 |

**Why is there a difference between RAID order and Linux device order?**